# How to localize EditButton in SwiftUI?

Tags: localization, swiftui

The `EditButton` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editbutton in SwiftUI seems can only display in English. Is there a way we can localize the text in the button?

```
NavigationView {
    List {

    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Test")
    .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing: Button(action: {
        
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own EditButton might be the way to go for now

```
struct NewEditButton: View {
    @Binding var editMode: EditMode
    var onDone: (() -> Void)?

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if self.editMode.isEditing {
                self.editMode = .inactive
                self.onDone?()
            } else {
                self.editMode = .active
            }
        }) {
            self.editMode == .active ? Text(NSLocalizedString("active", comment: "active")) : Text(NSLocalizedString("edit", comment: "edit"))
        }
    }
}
```

and then the external `editMode` state can be used to set the current editing model [In SwiftUI how do I set the environment variable of editMode in an XcodePreview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923351/in-swiftui-how-do-i-set-the-environment-variable-of-editmode-in-an-xcodepreview)